# Divide each three numbers of vector of by values in another vector

Tags: r

I would like to perform a simple calculation.

I have a vector of numbers:

```
> dput(DF_IS[,2])
c(0.00605997931747673, 0.00161894273127753, 0.00182572614107884, 
0.00133636363636364, 0.00379888268156425, 0.00172248803827751, 
0.000883211678832117, 0.0017481662591687, 0.00163145539906103, 
0.000837486457204767, 0.000321167883211679, 0.000825, 0.00144298688193744, 
0.000708860759493671, 0.000871599564744287, 0.000319108280254777, 
0.000518123667377399, 0.000363636363636364, 42.3517169614984, 
28.5714285714286, 50.4672897196262, 30.78125, 42.8571428571429, 
47.8781284004353, 0.0103960396039604, 0.0232472324723247, 0.0214780600461894
```

which contains 27 values and I would like to divide it by a vector of numbers below:

```
dput(DF_IS2[,1])
c(0.0031682160632777, 0.00228591145206846, 0.00142094444568728, 
0.000661218113472149, 0.0010078157353918, 0.000400289437089513, 
40.4634784175177, 40.5055070858594, 0.0183737773741582)
```

Second vector is 3 times shorter and it means that first 3 values from vector one should be divided by first number in second vector. Next, values `4-6` from first vector should be divided by `2nd` number in vector 2, etc. I would like to have it adjustable depending on number of replicates, etc.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Assuming 1st vector is called `x` and 2nd `y` we can put `x` in a matrix and do

```
n <- 3
c(t(matrix(x, ncol = n, byrow = TRUE)/y))
```

Or with `sweep`

```
c(sweep(matrix(x, nrow = n), 2, y, `/`))
```

Answer (score 1):

Try

```
dput(DF_IS[,2]) / rep(dput(DF_IS2[,1]), each=3)
```