# How to calculate SD for every 3 values in a vector?

Tags: r

I have a vector of numbers like below:

```
> dput(bb)
c(241.773096944017, 64.590451123677, 72.8404240633738, 100.901912491183, 
286.834000468988, 130.056170772738, 188.18474447343, 372.479473113113, 
347.612044485269, 284.319413999911, 109.033720563209, 280.080369696743, 
374.263819073223, 183.855403233492, 226.064551166099, 305.519052838205, 
496.059368888252, 348.150907607318, 382.602284309129, 258.112176357369, 
455.917769453671, 350.277011448521, 487.695331385902, 544.831926249031, 
149.254246073152, 333.756727381292, 308.357007228663)
```

I would like to group 3 following numbers and calculate standard deviation from it. However, I get strange results when I apply `sd` function one by one. Why is that ? How to do it in one code for every group of 3 numbers ?

```
> sd(bb[4:6])
[1] 100
> sd(bb[7:9])
[1] 100
> sd(bb[1:3])
[1] 100
> sd(bb[10:12])
[1] 100
> sd(bb[13:15])
[1] 100
```

Why it is always 100 ?

Comment: Try `zoo::rollapply(bb, 3, by = 3, sd)`

Comment: `> rollapply(bb, 3, by = 3, sd)
[1] 100 100 100 100 100 100 100 100 100`. Worked fine but still strange result. Thanks.

Comment: `apply(matrix(bb, 3), 2, sd)`

Comment: How did you generate those values?

Comment: Yeah, it's about how these numbers are generated. It doesn't happen, when you do `sd(bb[2:5])`

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60074727/divide-each-three-numbers-of-vector-of-by-values-in-another-vector[/link]. First answer and multiplied results by `100`.

Comment: The data was designed intentionally. Your question is how to generate numbers like that ?